# CSV export with interop

Tags: c#, excel, csv, interop, export

I'm using this code to generate an Excel file. It should be simple to change the export to CSV file, just by modifying a parameter in the saveAs call, but it doesn't work. Any ideea why ?

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlApp.Visible = false;
        if (xlApp == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("EXCEL could not be started. Check that your office installation and project references are correct.");
            return false;
        }
        Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        try
        {
            if (details != false)
            {
                //Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
                wb.Worksheets.Add();
                Worksheet detailsWs = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[2];
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    detailsWs.Cells[1, i + 1] = dt.Columns[i].Caption;
                }
            }
            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
            if (ws == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Worksheet could not be created. Check that your office installation and project references are correct.");
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                ws.Cells[1, i + 1] = dt.Columns[i].Caption;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j];
                }
                worker.ReportProgress((i * 100) / dt.Rows.Count);
            }

            wb.SaveAs(filename, XlFileFormat.xlCSV, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            wb.Close(true, filename);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Cleanup
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            if (wb != null)
            {
                wb.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wb);
            }
            if (xlApp != null)
            {
                xlApp.Quit();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It throws an exception :

Comment: this is the exception : Message = "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Comment: Don't "throw ex;" in your catch block, just "throw;" to get more information (stacktrace) or delete your catch block if you won't do there anything.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is and I'd suggest that you try to create a minimal version of your code that still exhibits the problem. However, looking at your code, your `catch` and `finally` are not very good.

As ibram said, just remove your catch block unless you're using it for something. And in your finally, why are you calling `GC.Collect` etc (and why twice?), and if you're calling `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` on the app and workbook, you should probably call it on the sheets you access as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i used the old way. lines of strings, with commas

Answer (score 2):

`XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared` is the reason. i don't know why but i get that error too. 
I try changing `XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange` and `XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive`,

it worked!